# C getting the 3 smallest numbers from an array

Tags: arrays, c

I'm taking a c programming course and one of the practice problems has left me stumped.

> In a swimming competition we want to implement an application to store the time of each competitor and then determine, based on all the competitors' times, which is the winner. The user must specify how many times they want to enter, it will print the 3 best times with the name of each of the competitors. There are 8 competitors

I can't use pointers because we haven't learned about them yet and I have to use functions. I have this so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void compare(){
//what do

}

int main(){
    int nTimes, f, c;
    float bestT[3];
    char bestN[3][50];
    char names[8][50];
    //User inputs the amount of times
    printf("Input how many times you wish to input: ");
    scanf("%i", &nTimes);
    //Validating that it is more than 1
    while(nTimes<1){
        printf("\nMust be 1 or more: ");
        scanf("%i", &nTimes);
    }
    //We ask for each competitor's name
    printf("\nInput each competitor's name: ");
    for(c=0; c<8; c++){
        scanf("%s", &names[c]);
    }
    //Create matrix
    float times[nTimes][8];
    for(f=0;f<nTimes;f++){
        for(c=0;c<8;c++){
            printf("\nInput time %i for %s: ", f+1, names[c]);
            scanf("%f", &times[f][c]);
            while(times[f][c]<0){
                printf("\nTime must be bigger than 0.00: ");
                scanf("%f", &times[f][c]);
            }
        }
    }
    //confusion
    return 0;

}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone would point me in the right direction.

Comment: OT: `for(f=0;f<nTimes;f++){` vs. `for( f = 0; f < nTimes; f++ ) {`... Which of these two is easier to read? You don't have to pay more for inserting spaces to s p r e a d t h i n g s o u t...

Comment: Right direction? Do you know about `struct`? Use a `struct` to keep each swimmer and their time(s) together as one unit.

Comment: Once you have an array of structures, it's easy to read *all* data into this array, and then use [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) to sort the array. When you have your sorted array, you can get the three "lowest" values of that array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Although to use `qsort`, they have to use pointers, so that may not be allowed. It's a strange set of restrictions though.

Comment: What are the criteria if 2 competitors tie for 1st place, or 2nd place, or 3rd place? Or 3 competitors? What if all 8 competitors complete the competition in exactly the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you could do is the following:

- create a data structure to hold the 3 top times and corresponding competitors
- iterate over the best 3 times of all competitors
- compare them against the best 3 times descending, that is, you start
  with the first place if none of the 3 times beat that continue with
  the 2nd place and so on
- if it beats any of the ranks, replace
  the previous competitor and time with the current one and continue with the next competitor.

at the end you
have the 3 best performing athletes stored in your data structure.

Comment: I think you need a slight improvement to the the "top three" vector you're talking about. For example, if we have `int top[3]` and its current values are: `23,37,62` If we get a new score of `17`, just replacing `top[0]` isn't sufficient because we'd get: `17,37,62` instead of [the correct] `17,23,37`. We need to "slide" the current and subsequent entries to the right to make room for the entry we're adding. With `17,23,37` and adding `19`, we want: `17,19,23`

Comment: oh yes, it sounds like we would skip comparing the next tier, thats not what i meant. good point. i also shoulve pointed out that the first competitor should be assigned to first, second and third place at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you can't use structs to group the name and time if you're restricted to not using pointers.

It may be easiest to figure this out *as* you're reading data in. On each read you can update the data in arrays that track your winners' times and names.

*Note that this does not error check `scanf`. That is left as an exercise for the OP.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int top3times[3] = {0};
    char top3names[3][50];

    int num_entries = 0;

    printf("Input numbers of times and names:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num_entries);

    int times[num_entries];
    char names[num_entries][50];

    for (int i = 0; i < num_entries; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &times[i]);
        scanf("%49s", names[i]);

        if (times[i] < top3times[0] || i == 0) {
            top3times[2] = top3times[1];
            top3times[1] = top3times[0];
            top3times[0] = times[i];

            strcpy(top3names[2], top3names[1]);
            strcpy(top3names[1], top3names[0]);
            strcpy(top3names[0], names[i]);
        } 
        else if (times[i] < top3times[1] || i == 1) {
            top3times[2] = top3times[1];
            top3times[1] = times[i];

            strcpy(top3names[2], top3names[1]);
            strcpy(top3names[1], names[i]);
        }
        else if (times[i] < top3times[2] || i == 2) {
            top3times[2] = times[i];

            strcpy(top3names[2], names[i]);
        }
    }
   
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%s => %d\n", top3names[i], top3times[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure its not to hard. Once you get all your times in your array you want to iterate through them and compare. So without giving the answer fully you want to check usually with an if statement although there are many ways, inside a while or for and then use another variable so that if the number in the array is bigger than the number in the variable you make the variable equal to the current number in the array. Then for simplicity sake once you find the biggest number you can find the second biggest number by making the variable equal to the second lowest number in the array and so on and then print results. So the way I would make the second one would be something akin to:

```
while(x<ntimes){
if(times[][]<myvarible && myvariable> myfastesttime){myvariable=times[][]}

x++;}
```

hopefully this points you without giving away to much